# Rails, Foundation 4, Respond.js not working properly in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ruby-on-rails-3.2, media-queries, zurb-foundation, respond.js

I have a Rails 3.2 project with Foundation 4 and I need to support Internet Explorer 8.

To enable the media queries in IE8 needed by the Foundation 4 grid I included Respond.js.
I tested in IE8, but the layout remained the small devices layout. The respond.js testpage worked fine in IE8.

Why isn't the Foundation grid properly loaded in IE8?

Answer (score 3):

I previously enabled sass support in Google Chrome and had `config.sass.debug_info = true` in `environments/development.rb` and the resulting `@media -sass-debug-info` apparently aren't processed by respond.js.

Changing `config.sass.debug_info` to `false`, emptying the `tmp/cache/` project folder and restarting the rails server solved this issue.

*edit*
Apparently I also have to set

```
config.sass.debug_info = false
config.sass.line_comments = false
```

to completely disable the sass debug media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that IE8 doesn't seem to like the @import-property.

We used a global css file which imported the necessary styles. When moving all stylesheets to the assets pipeline via =* require custom.css it all started working

It's weird though, the regular bootstrap styling (buttons, backgrounds and such) got imported properly. The grid system was not. I guess Internet Explorer works in mysterious and retarded ways.